# Will PS+ allow me to play online with another profile on the same PS4 that doesn't have a PS+ subscription?

Tags: playstation-plus

I bought a PS4 and it already had a PSN profile, so I created my own profile and used the original PSN profile to play online. Now the PlayStation Plus subscription is about to expire.

Instead of renewing the original profiles PS+ subscription, I want to purchase a new PS+ subscription for my new PSN profile.

The problem is I pre-ordered CoD: Black Ops 3 with original PSN profile and don't want to buy PS+ subscription for my profile if I won't be able play the game online.

I would renew original profiles PS+ subscription if I it meant I could still play the game on my own PSN profile.

Comment: You are going to need to talk to Sony PSN support for this I believe, nothing we can help you with here.. well in regards the profile oddness. Save games are usually tied to PSN account but that can vary game to game.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but your account that has PS+ must be registered as the primary account on the PS4 you use.

[Source](https://support.us.playstation.com/articles/en_US/KC_Article/PS4-Online-Multiplayer-Requirements/?)